# furnace question

Tags: furnace

I have a tenant that constantly sets the thermostat at 90 degrees for the heat.  I have told her several times to stop because she will burn the unit up. What are the consequences of this and how long will it take for me to notice problems with the unit?

Comment: Is it a gas or electric unit? Who pays the gas/electric bill?

Answer (score 4):

For a correctly installed and maintained furnace, the only consequence is slightly reduced combustion efficiency. That is well within the range of temperatures furnaces are designed to endure.